# Hyperledger Fabric ledger files and composer-rest-server files

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

i want to know that where the ledger file of hyperledger fabric resides and in which format?

Also i want to have a look on endpoints and the server file generated by composer-rest-server command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This section of the Key Concepts](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ledger/ledger.html) in the Hyperledger Fabric Documentation will help you with the storage and format of the Ledger.

The composer-rest-server has a `swagger.json` doc which describes the endpoints. Typically found at http://localhost:3000/explorer/swagger.json

Comment: ok but i want to make some changes to some endpoints. Where is the file and can i edit it? @R Thatcher

Comment: The endpoints are dynamically generated based on the business network definition, so the only way to influence the composer-rest-server is through the model definition of the business network